# Implementing JTreeTable in swing

Tags: java, swing, jtreetable

I would like to implement a JTreeTable. I saw the example in the official java website. I am a beginner to java and i am not able to understand that example. I have the tree node and child names as a string. How do i implement it?

Comment: You do not have to *implement* JTreeTable, it is already implemented. Just follow the steps [in the tutorial](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/treetable1/) and you'll be fine. If you experience any problems, come back with an SSCCE. If the tutorial is not comprehensible to you, learn more Java first.

Comment: ^ tutorial link is broken. (Thanks Oracle. >:( sigh.)

Comment: can someone share the new tutorial links of Oracle for JTreeTable ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are (only products I tried)

free

- [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net/)
- NetBeans [`Outline`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/Outline.html), illustrated [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui/4447#4447)
- excellent workaround by [aephyr](http://aephyr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/)
- simple code example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/JTreeTablecomponent.htm)

non-free

- [JIDE Grids](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/grids.htm)

maybe more information you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bjava%5D%20treetable)